# MSChart axis moves depending on text size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

Does anybody now how to prevent the Y-axis from moving (horizontally) when the text area increases (for example when displaying 100 instead of 1 on a label on the Y-axis).

The following image illustrates the problem; when a decimal is added to the number on the labels, the diagram is resized and the Y-axis is moved to the right:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `Axis` and other a few other `ChartElements` may move is that their `Positions` are set to `Automatic` by default; so when the lables need more space they get it and the inner portion is reduced.

So if you want to prevent that you need to set an explicit values for the `X` values of its `Position`.

Note that the values are in **percent** of the respective containers.

Unless you set a special `Crossing` value, the primary axes are always drawn to the left and bottom of the `InnerPlotArea`.

So you want to set the position, maybe like this:

```
ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ca.InnerPlotPosition.X = 10;
```

Note however, that this means: The `Y-Axis` will start at `10%` of the `whole` `ChartArea.Width`, which usually means something like `'almost 10%'` of the whole `Chart.Width`. (The `Legend` and some white space will usually take some space, too).

So if you resize your chart the axis may sit a little too much to the right.. You may want ot play with the number and maybe code an extra line in the `Resize` event of the Chart.